# В PyCharm файл на русском языке (словарь русского языка) выводится непонятными символами

Tags: python, pycharm, кириллица

Вот кусок кода, в котором нужно ввести слово, затем идет чтение файла, копия всего текста в переменную, и вывод текста на экран:

```
first_gamer_word = input("Первый игрок\n")
file = open('D:\\russian_nouns.txt', 'r')
text = file.read()
file.close()
print(text)
```

Вот пример того что выдаёт PyCharm:

```
Р°Р±Р°Р¶СѓСЂ
Р°Р±Р°Р¶СѓСЂС‡РёРє
Р°Р±Р°Р·
Р°Р±Р°Р·РёРЅ
Р°Р±Р°Р·РёРЅРµС†
```

Comment: Какая версия питона и какая кодировка файла?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа

Comment: CrazyElf, Кодировка файла -  windows-1251, a версия питона 3.8. Сам файл с текстом в кодировке UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_gamer_word = input("Первый игрок\n")
file = open('D:\\russian_nouns.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
text = file.read()
file.close()
print(text)
```

***stdout***:

```
абажур
абажурчик
абаз
абазин
абазинец
```

Comment: Схема из этой статьи https://habr.com/ru/post/147843/ говорит, что файл изначально в utf-8, а был открыт в cp1251. Соответственно при открытии файла нужно utf-8 указывать.